# Input mask should accept five digits also

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, mask

I am using jQuery input mask plugin like:

```
var s = jQuery.noConflict();
    s(document).ready(function () {
    s(".zipmask").mask('99999-9999');
});
```

It accepts the numbers like 12345-1111 and works fine.
Now I want that it should support five digits like if we enter "12345" only, It should accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use it like this way: Anything after the '?' is optional.

```
s(function(){
    s(".zipmask").mask("99999?-9999");
});
```

Comment: now it accept numbers like 3456777777-7777. This should not happen.... it should accept numbers like 34567-7777 or 34567

Comment: The best way to restrict is try `maxlength` property of html. Try this ``<input type="text" name="zipmask" class="zipmask" maxlength="10">``

Comment: i added max length property to textbox.. it still accept 123467896-7777

Comment: Sorry sorry. Please use this. This must work. s(".zipmask").mask("99999?-9999"); Sorry for the inconvenience. I will update my answer, please verify and report back.

Comment: Updating the answer!

Answer (score 0):

In my case following code is working like a charm.

```
        var zipcodeLength = 0;
        $('[mask=zipcode]').on("focus", function () {
            $('[mask=zipcode]').mask('00000-0000');
        });
        $('[mask=zipcode]').on("change", function () {
            $('[mask=zipcode]').mask('00000-0000');
            zipcodeLength = $(this).val().replace(/[^0-9]/g, "").length;
            if (zipcodeLength > 5) {
                $(this).mask('00000-0000', { clearIfNotMatch: true });
            } else {
                $(this).mask('00000', { clearIfNotMatch: true });
            }
        });
```